# Remove all the applications/softwares from your machine without formatting it

Tags: format, jdk, ruby-on-rails

I want to remove everything that has been installed on my machine without formatting my machine.

For example, I have Ruby on Rails installed, JDK and number of dependencies which are required for a Hydra projects.

Applications such as Redit, Fits, Solr are also installed on my machine.

Now Is there any way with which I can remove these things all at once or any other better way to do this?

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you want to keep?  Where do you draw the line between 'software' and the basic operating system? If you only want the original operating systen, it is probably easiest to *reinstall Ubuntu*. That way 'everything else' will be overwritten. I think it is almost impossible to find and remove everything that has been installed.

Comment: Formatting is probably the best option of you want a "like new" system.